# Is there any side effect if I clone a repo and rename it?

Tags: mercurial

I have central mercurial repository server. I cloned repoA on my local system 
initiated new repoB on central server. cloned repob to local. copied everything from repoA to repoB, commit and pushed to repoB (central server)

now i have all the changeset history from repoA on this new repoB 
there was a need to do so as there were two application code on same repoA, to separate it i did the above experiment. and it is working.

my question is by doing so is there any side effects , or is there a better way to do it (recommended way ) please suggest, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a repository to your local PC, the repository lives in a folder. That name of that folder is typically how people refer to the "name of the clone" or the "name of the repository".

Other than that, the folder name itself has very little significance and is not even properly part of the Mercurial repository.

It sounds like you did several other steps, but basically if you renamed repository `A` to `B` it won't make much difference (but see notes below).

---

You do not need to use `hg clone` to clone a repository. You can literally just copy the entire repository folder and the copy will work just fine. The one difference that I am aware of when you use `clone` vs. operating system file copy is that the clone will point back to the repo you cloned from (for use in push/pull operations). The copy would point back to the *original* source. (See notes below about some related effects).

---

One situation where you might cause some problems by renaming the repository folder is if you have have cloned FROM it. Example: you have local repo `A`. You clone `A` to `B`. Now internal to the configuration data in `B` is a reference to the folder path including `A`. If you rename `A` to `A1` then that path is obviously broken.

In such a situation you can easily edit the `B/.hg/hgrc` file and  modify the line starting with `default=` to correct the path.

---

Based on your question it sounded like you copied a bunch of stuff from one repo to another. Presumably this also included the `.hg` folder. Generally speaking I recommend avoiding the contents of that folder, and always approach it with caution.

Although technically some of it is human-readable it is simpler & safer to treat it as a black box, or you risk corrupting your repository. There are occasional exceptions (like `hgrc`) but they are few & far between.

Of course if you are just trying to learn how it works then by all means try things & see what happens!  One of the great Mercurial features is the ability to copy a repo, mess around with it, and throw it away when done.